# Write a function to remove object if it exists

Tags: function, r

I am trying to write a function that removes an object if it exists. The reason is that I want to get rid of the log-message Error: object 'arg' not found. I tried the following:

```
ifrm <- function(arg)
{
   if(exists(as.character(substitute(arg)))){rm(arg)}
}
```

Unfortunately this does not remove the object if it exists

```
> ifrm <- function(arg)
+ {
+    if(exists(as.character(substitute(arg)))){rm(arg)}
+ }
> a <- 2
> ifrm(a)
> a
[1] 2
```

Any hints what I do wrong here?

Best Albrecht

Comment: This sounds like a possibly dangerous thing to do.  Do you want to give us a bit more detail about the circumstances where you get this error?  There may be other ways of dealing with your error message that are more appropriate.

Comment: I agree with Andrie.  The answers provided will do what you asked, but most likely what you actually should be doing is even simpler.  Take a look at try and trycatch.  What is it that you're trying to do that is attempting to process nonexistent objects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A general idiom to grab what the user supplied as an argument to a function is `deparse(substitute(foo))`. This function is similar to that of @Ian Ross but employing this standard idiom:

```
ifrm <- function(obj, env = globalenv()) {
    obj <- deparse(substitute(obj))
    if(exists(obj, envir = env)) {
        rm(list = obj, envir = env)
    }
}
```

where I assume you only ever want to remove objects from the global environment, hence the default, but you can supply an environment via `env`. And here it is in action:

```
> a <- 1:10
> ls()
[1] "a"    "ifrm"
> ifrm(a)
> ls()
[1] "ifrm"
> ifrm(a)
> ls()
[1] "ifrm"
```

Comment: One should add a warning that using deparse(substitute()) in a nested function is bound to give trouble. myrm <- function(x) ifrm(x) will not do what you think it does...

Comment: @Joris +1 good point, but then one could say, don't do that! ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
 a=1; b=3; y=4; ls() 
 rm( list = Filter( exists, c("a", "b", "x", "y") ) )
 ls()
```

Answer (score 4):

Keep it simple.  Just pass the name of the object into your function as a character string, rather than trying to get the name from the actual object.

```
ifrm <- function(x, env = globalenv()) 
{
  if(exists(x, envir = env)) 
  {
    rm(list = x, envir = env)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of ugly, but it seems to work:

```
ifrm <- function(arg) {
  if (exists(as.character(substitute(arg)))) {
    rm(list=as.character(substitute(arg)), envir=sys.frame())
  }
}
```

You might want to specify the environment differently if you're not removing names from the top-level environment.