# A function to delete everything

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function to clear the global environment in R since I am too lazy to type `rm(list=ls(all=T))` every time.

I tried

```
purge = function(){
    rm(list=ls(all=T), envir = globalenv())
}
```

and

```
purge = function(){
    rm(list=ls(all=T), pos = 1)
}
```

but they don't seem to be doing anything. There is a similar question that is targeted to a single object [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172568/write-a-function-to-remove-object-if-it-exists) but all I want to do is to clear everything in one go every single time. (I realize this function will also be gone after that but that is not an issue)

Comment: `purge <- function(all = FALSE) rm(list = ls(.GlobalEnv, all.names = all), envir = .GlobalEnv)`, ie, you need to set the environment in `ls` also since it defaults to the current environment and not the global

Comment: Yup forgot about ls's arguments. Thanks

Comment: If you made it `.purge` (dot in front) and removed `all = TRUE` it wouldn't be removed when you called it. I wouldn't do `all = TRUE` personally, because you'd also be removing the `.Random.seed`

Comment: Another way to not delete the function is to put it in an environment and attach the environment to the search path: `local({MyFuns <- new.env(); MyFuns$purge <- function(all = FALSE) rm(list = ls(.GlobalEnv, all.names = all), envir = .GlobalEnv); attach(MyFuns)})`